# Bring back a closed file watcher notification in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

I am using PhpStorm in my project which includes a `.scss` file.
I have been using a third party program to compile sass files. now I decided to use PhpStorm internal File Watcher.

I have followed the instruction to setup ruby on my Windows and now I want to use File Watcher.

The problem is I have closed the notification box for file watcher ( you know that box with a round close icon appears in the right top ) now I want to bring it back. How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If such notification was disabled for specific file type, then to bring such notification back do the following:

1. `Settings (Preferences on Mac) | Tools | File Watchers`
2. Click on `Edit Suppressed File Watchers` icon (the icon that looks like guy in a hat; it may look like it's disabled, but it's actually working)
3. Remove specific entry from that list

---

If we talking about notification in general -- have a look at `Settings (Preferences on Mac) | Appearance & Behaviour | Notifications` -- possibly you have disabled "File Watchers" entry altogether.

---

I personally see no reason about enabling such notification again (unless you want to have it in other projects). I would just go and create required File Watcher straight away (IDE should help with default values). In any case, here is a official article/how-to: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/File+Watchers+in+PhpStorm

Comment: There was no entry in my suppressed file watcher list. but thanks, I am trying the other way you explained.

Comment: another question: how can I config sass in ruby to output css file in extended or compressed or other ways possible?

Comment: I was looking for the way to open this small window for hours. They really managed to hide this button. Thanks.